# Creating Custom Keymaps in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

How does one create a VBA keyboard shortcut in Excel?
I DO NOT want to use the GUI. I want to do it programatically.
Is that possible?

Is the OnKey function meant to be part of the Sub it is accessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a seperate`Sub` to set the Keys you require using

```
Application.OnKey(Key, ProcedureName)
```

This sub can then be run in a variety of ways, eg run from `Alt-F8` menu, run from the VBA IDE, assigned to a command bar button, of run from from the `Workbook_Open` event